# Create contextual Snippet for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Is there a way to create a *contextual* snippet proposition for VS Code ?
I am trying to add custom snippets to the css.json file that take into account if I am in a specific tag.
Explanation, I want to get this code when I type `bckgd` as a `div` property.

```
div {
        background: color position size repeat origin clip attachment image;
    }
```

But I don't want it to show me this snippet if the cursor is not inside of a tag.

Comment: You say `if the cursor is not inside of a tag` do you mean not inside a `div` tag?  So that `bckgd` would work in `div` tags only and not other types of tags?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently use user defined snippets for that but you can [write an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) that implements VS Code's `CompletionItemProvider` to conditionally return snippets.

The relevant apis are:

- [`CompletionItemProvider`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/completions-sample) — This is invoked when a user requests completions. The completion item provider can check the current document to decide which completions to return
- [`SnippetString`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SnippetString) — A snippet. Your completion item provider can return these